# having trouble with this quadratic equation class JAVA

Tags: java

I need to write a code that solves a quadratic equation and displays a message if there are no solutions, when I run the program no matter what numbers I use I always get the third if statement where there are no solutions.

```
public class Quadratic {



private double a, b, c, x, x1, x2;

    public Quadratic() {
        a = b = c = 1;
    }

    public Quadratic(double a1, double b1, double c1) {
        a = a1;
        b = b1;
        c = c1;
    }

    public double getA() {
        return a;
    }

    public double getB() {
        return b;
    }

    public double getC() {
        return c;
    }

    public void setA(double a2) {
        a = a2;
    }

    public void setB(double b2) {
        b = b2;
    }

    public void setC(double c2) {
        c = c2;
    }

    public void setQuadratic(double a3, double b3, double c3) {
        a = a3;
        b = b3;
        c = c3;
    }

    public void roots() {
        System.out.println(a + "x^2 + " + b + "x + " + c + " = 0");

        if (Math.pow(b, 2) - 4 * a * c == 0) {
            System.out.println("Solution: (" + oneSolution() + ")");
        }

        if (Math.pow(b, 2) - 4 * a * c > 0) {
            System.out.println("Solutions: (" + solution1() + "," + solution2() + ")");
        }

        if (Math.pow(b, 2) - 4 * a * c < 0) {
            System.out.println("Solutions: There are no solutions");
        }

    }

    public double oneSolution() {
        x = -b / 2 * a;
        return x;
    }

    public double solution1() {
        x1 = (-b + (Math.sqrt(Math.pow(b, 2) - 4 * a * c))) / (2 * a);
        return x1;
    }

    public double solution2() {
        x2 = (-b - (Math.sqrt(Math.pow(b, 2) - 4 * a * c))) / (2 * a);
        return x2;
    }

}
```

Comment: What are your test case values for `a`, `b`, and `c`?

Answer (score 1):

your code seems to work :-)

I took your class and did the following:

```java
class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Quadratic q = new Quadratic(1.0, 2.0, -35.0);
        q.roots();
    }
}
```

The output was:

```
1.0x^2 + 2.0x + -35.0 = 0
Solutions: (5.0,-7.0)
```

And this is correct!

Answer (score 0):

try to use 2. or 2.0 instead of 2: 2.0, 4.0 etc...
if that doesnt work, try 2.0d etc, or declare your constants: double two = 2.0;

maybe that makes it work, im not sure about java handling e.g. double / integer .. so it probably better you do a double / double

Comment: Java converts literals to the declared variable types, so I don't think it's the case.